# Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RangeSlider" was not found in UIManager

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm, uimanager

I am trying to use this package to create a range slider:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-range-slider

```
import React from 'react';
import { Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, Switch, Button } from "react-native";
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import DatePicker from 'react-native-datepicker';
import RangeSlider from 'react-native-range-slider';

<View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
    <RangeSlider
     minValue={0}
     maxValue={100}
     tintColor={'#da0f22'}
     handleBorderWidth={1}
     handleBorderColor="#454d55"
     selectedMinimum={20}
     selectedMaximum={40}
     style={{ flex: 1, height: 70, padding: 10, backgroundColor: '#ddd' }}
     onChange={ (data)=>{ console.log(data);} }
     />
</View>
```

however keep running into the error: 
Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RangeSlider" was not found in UIManager.

I was able to successfully install the package and ran 
react-native link react-native-range-slider to link the library as well but I still get the error.

I am running:
    react-native-cli: 2.0.1 and 
    react-native: 0.59.8

Can someone please help me out in fixing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You will receive this error on Android as it's only supported for iOS as of current.